# Where can I find test instances for convex quadratic programming?

Tags: quadratic-programming, test-instances

I am looking for (sources of) convex quadratic programming instances with linear constraints. I am open for both continuous and mixed integer problems, but do not want randomly generated instances.

I am aware of [QPLIB](http://qplib.zib.de/index.html), a collection of various types of convex/noncovex, integer/continuous, linearly constrained/quadratically constrained quadratic programmes.

I am also aware of the [Maros and Meszaros test set](http://www.cuter.rl.ac.uk/Problems/marmes.shtml).

Comment: Maybe this deserves a [test-instances] tag?

Comment: yes I was wondering how the tag should be named, [testset], [test-instances], [benchmarks]..

Comment: Seems like you're the first one to need it, so I guess you get to decide. :)

Answer (score 11):

There are at least three more problem libraries that you can access.

1. [OR-Lib](http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastjjb/jeb/info.html) has instances of Quadratic Assignment/Knapsack/Minimum spanning tree that you can use.
2. [MINLP-Lib](http://www.minlplib.org/instances.html) has several QP, BQP, IQP instances that you can filter by convexity.
3. [PrincetonLib](http://titan.princeton.edu/TestProblems/chapter2.html) chapter 2 problems.

I think that you can apart of it come up with synthetic instances which are not completely random (you provide certain structure) easily, like Quadratic assignment problems.

Comment: Thanks! I think all the problems in PrincetonLib Chapter 2 are nonconvex. QAP usually is nonconvex as well, but OR-Lib also seems to have portfolio rebalancing/optimization instances, which might be convex. MINLP-Lib has some overlap with QPLIB, but there are some more in there.

Answer (score 8):

You can reformulate Quadratic Programs as Second Order Conic Programs (SOCPs). Therefore, you can use many conic benchmark libraries and filter SOCPs.

For example, [Conic Benchmark Library](http://cblib.zib.de/) can be a good start!

Comment: But not every SOCP can be reformulated as a convex QP with linear constraints, right? My question aims at the situation of having a new solver for convex, linearly constrained QP and wanting to test it with as many problem instances as possible.

Comment: Yes, i mean you can find the linearly constrained qp's. I am looking if there is a general library for what you look for.